# Parser Error: Missing expected ) at column, and Property 'abc' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: angular, angular-material, nestjs, angular-httpclient

I'm writing code in angular first time. **I'm connecting nestJs with angular**. Below is the code and the errors I'm facing when I'm putting my CRUD methods into html file. I'm missing logics. If someone need more details and data I will provide that as well.

**Errors**

```
Error: src/app/genres/genres.component.html:59:79 - error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type '{}'.

59           <input matInput placeholder="Name" name="name" [(ngModel)] = "genre.name" required>
                                                                                 ~~~~

  src/app/genres/genres.component.ts:6:16
    6   templateUrl: './genres.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component GenresComponent.



Error: src/app/genres/genres.component.html:62:83 - error TS2339: Property 'floor' does not exist on type '{}'.

62             <input matInput placeholder="Title" name="title" [(ngModel)] = "genre.floor" required>
                                                                                     ~~~~~

  src/app/genres/genres.component.ts:6:16
    6   templateUrl: './genres.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component GenresComponent.


Error: src/app/genres/genres.component.html:66:83 - error TS2339: Property 'genres_number' does not exist on type '{}'.  

66             <input matInput placeholder="Email" name="email" [(ngModel)] = "genre.genres_number" required>
                                                                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/genres/genres.component.ts:6:16
    6   templateUrl: './genres.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component GenresComponent.

                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component GenresComponent.


Error: src/app/genres/genres.component.html:69:83 - error TS2339: Property 'shelves' does not exist on type '{}'.        

69             <input matInput placeholder="Phone" name="phone" [(ngModel)] = "genre.shelves" required>
                             

    
Error: src/app/genres/genres.component.html:76:44 - error NG5002: Parser Error: Unexpected token ')' at column 21 in [addgenres(genre: any)] in D:\Noum\Data\CYBRNODE\Flutter\library-project-Angular-frontend\library\src\app\genres\genres.component.html@75:43

76         <button mat-raised-button (click)="addgenres(genre: any)" color="primary">Add Genres</button>
                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/genres/genres.component.ts:6:16
    6   templateUrl: './genres.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component GenresComponent.

                                                ~~~~~~~

  src/app/genres/genres.component.ts:6:16
    6   templateUrl: './genres.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component GenresComponent.


Error: src/app/genres/genres.component.html:76:45 - error NG5002: Parser Error: Missing expected ) at column 16 in [addgenres(genre: any)] in D:\Noum\Data\CYBRNODE\Flutter\library-project-Angular-frontend\library\src\app\genres\genres.component.html@75:44

76         <button  mat-raised-button (click)="addgenres(genre: any)" color="primary">Add Genres</button>
                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/genres/genres.component.ts:6:16
    6   templateUrl: './genres.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component GenresComponent.


Error: src/app/genres/genres.component.html:76:45 - error NG5002: Parser Error: Unexpected token ')' at column 21 in [addgenres(genre: any)] in D:\Noum\Data\CYBRNODE\Flutter\library-project-Angular-frontend\library\src\app\genres\genres.component.html@75:44

76         <button  mat-raised-button (click)="addgenres(genre: any)" color="primary">Add Genres</button>
                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/genres/genres.component.ts:6:16
    6   templateUrl: './genres.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component GenresComponent.
```

**genres.component.ts file**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-genres',
  templateUrl: './genres.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./genres.component.css']
})
export class GenresComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'floor', 'genre_number', 'shelves'];
  dataSource = [];
  genre = {};
  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
  getallgenres() {
    this.apiService.getallgenres().subscribe
      ((result) => {
        this.dataSource != result;
      })
  }
  addgenres(genre: any) {
    this.apiService.addgenres(genre.value).subscribe((result) => {
      console.log(result);
    });
  }

  async putupdateGenres(genre: any) {
    (await (this.apiService.putupdategenre(genre.value))).subscribe((result: any) => {
      console.log(result);
    });
  }
  async patchupdateGenres(genre: any) {
    ((this.apiService.patchupdategenres(genre.value))).subscribe((result: any) => {
      console.log(result);
    });
  }
  deletegenres(id: any) {
    this.apiService.deletegenres(id).subscribe((result) => {
      console.log(result);
    });
  }

}
```

**genres.component.html file(here I'm passing my functions and errors are showing here**

```
<mat-card>
    <mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-title>All Genres</mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content>
        <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8" style="width: 100%;">
            <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let genres"> {{genres.id}} </td>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let genres"> {{genres.name}} </td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="floor">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Floor Number </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let genres"> {{genres.floor}} </td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="genres_number">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Number of Genres </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let genres"> {{genres.genres_number}} </td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="shelves">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Number of Shelves </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let genres"> {{genres.shelves}} </td>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Genres Number </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let genres">
                    <button mat-raised-button (click)="deletegenres(genres.id)" color="secondary">Delete Genres</button>


                </td>
            </ng-container>



            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
        </table>

    </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>




<mat-card>
    <mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-title>Add Genres</mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content>
        <form #f="ngForm" class="mat-elevation-z8" style="width: 100%; padding: 5px;">

            <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput placeholder="Name" name="name" [(ngModel)]="genre.name" required>
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput placeholder="Title" name="title" [(ngModel)]="genre.floor" required>
            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput placeholder="Email" name="email" [(ngModel)]="genre.genres_number" required>
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput placeholder="Phone" name="phone" [(ngModel)]="genre.shelves" required>
            </mat-form-field>

        </form>

    </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-actions>
        <button mat-raised-button (click)="addgenres(genre: any)" color="primary">Add Genres</button>
        <button mat-raised-button (click)="putupdateGenres(genre: any)" color="primary">Put Update Genres</button>
        <button mat-raised-button (click)="patchupdateGenres(genre: any)" color="primary">Patch Update Genres</button>

    </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

**UPDATED PART. api.service.ts file**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Genres } from './genres_schema';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {
  API_SERVER = "http://localhost:3000";
  constructor(private httpclient: HttpClient) { }

  public getallgenres() {
    return this.httpclient.get<Genres[]>(`${this.API_SERVER}/genres`)
  }
  public getdepartmentbyid(genreID: Genres) {
    return this.httpclient.get<Genres>(`${this.API_SERVER}/genres/${genreID}/singlegenres`)
  }
  async getallBooksofSingleGenere(name: string) {
    return this.httpclient.get<Genres>(`${this.API_SERVER}/genres/${{ genres_name: name }}/bookofsinglegenres`)
  }
  public addgenres(genres: Genres) {
    return this.httpclient.post<Genres>(`${this.API_SERVER}/genres/add`, genres);
  }
  async putupdategenre(genre_id: string) {
    return this.httpclient.put<Genres>(`${this.API_SERVER}/genres/${genre_id}/putupdate`, genre_id);
  }
  public patchupdategenres(genre_id: Genres) {
    return this.httpclient.put<Genres>(`${this.API_SERVER}/genres/${genre_id}/patchupdate`, genre_id);
  }

  public deletegenres(id: number) {
    return this.httpclient.delete(`${this.API_SERVER}/genres/${id}/delete`);
  }
}
```

**Updated Error**

[image]

Comment: Specify `genre` as `any` type. `genre: any = {};`. And you **can't specify the variable type in HTML**. `addgenres(genre)`. Same goes for the next 2 functions

Comment: The issue is solved, but the forms are not showing and the buttons also not working can you suggest me something, or tell why it's not working?

Comment: Can you provide sample data from `this.apiService.getallgenres()`. Meanwhile in this method, `this.dataSource != result;` `!=` is not equal sign, it is comparable operator, you need to use `=` to assign value.

Comment: And in HTML, `matColumnDef="genres_number"` was wrong. I think you mean `matColumnDef="genre_number"` based on `displayedColumns`.

Comment: When I use displayedColumns it give me error `Property 'shelves' does not exist on type 'string[] `. when I use `=` it give me error `Type 'Genres[]' is not assignable to type 'never[].
  Type 'Genres' is not assignable to type 'never`. when I use `==` the error is gone can explain the meaning of this logic here?

Comment: And about `this.apiService.getallgenre()`, function shows all the genres. a genre has 4 properties that are mentioned in `displayedColumns: string[]=['']`, and id is generated by `mongoDB` automatically. Also I've added my `api.service file as well in my question` you can see if it helps

Comment: also i've added some errors